# Cuda idx doesnt index matrices correctly

Tags: cuda

I have the following kernel in cuda:

```
__global__ void pagerank(Node *ingoing, Node *outgoing, int N) {
   int j;
   int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 
    if ((idx > 0) && (idx < N)){
      //for(j=0;j<N;j++){
      //   outgoing[j].p_t1=ingoing[j].p_t1;  
      //}
      outgoing[idx].p_t1=ingoing[idx].p_t1; 

  }
}
```

This doesnt work. The following works:

```
__global__ void pagerank(Node *ingoing, Node *outgoing, int N) {
       int j;
       int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 
        if ((idx > 0) && (idx < N)){
          for(j=0;j<N;j++){
             outgoing[j].p_t1=ingoing[j].p_t1;  
          }
          //outgoing[idx].p_t1=ingoing[idx].p_t1; 

      }
    }
```

What is wrong? Why idx doesnt index the matrices correctly?

The whole code is written below. It wouldn't be so easy to understand it. The thing is that when I print the outgoing[idx].p_t1 fields at the end of the main function they print 0s when I do

```
outgoing[idx].p_t1=ingoing[idx].p_t1;
```

but they are correct when I do

```
for(j=0;j<N;j++){
   outgoing[j].p_t1=ingoing[j].p_t1;  
}
```

Whats wrong?

```
/******************** Includes - Defines ****************/
#include "pagerank_serial.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "string.h"

/******************** Defines ****************/
// Number of nodes
int N;

// Convergence threashold and algorithm's parameter d  
double threshold, d;

// Table of node's data
Node *Nodes;

__global__ void pagerank(Node *ingoing, Node *outgoing, int N) {
       int j;
       int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 
        if ((idx > 0) && (idx < N)){
          for(j=0;j<N;j++){
             outgoing[j].p_t1=ingoing[j].p_t1;  
          }
          //outgoing[idx].p_t1=ingoing[idx].p_t1; 

      }
    } 
/***** Read graph connections from txt file *****/  

void Read_from_txt_file(char* filename)
{

FILE *fid;

int from_idx, to_idx;
int temp_size;

fid = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fid == NULL){
   printf("Error opening data file\n");
}

while (!feof(fid))
{

  if (fscanf(fid,"%d\t%d\n", &from_idx,&to_idx))
  {
     Nodes[from_idx].con_size++;
     temp_size = Nodes[from_idx].con_size;
     //Nodes[from_idx].To_id =(int*) realloc(Nodes[from_idx].To_id, temp_size * sizeof(int));
     Nodes[from_idx].To_id[temp_size - 1] = to_idx;
   }
}

//printf("End of connections insertion!\n");

fclose(fid);

 }

/***** Read P vector from txt file*****/    

void Read_P_from_txt_file()
{

FILE *fid;
double temp_P;
int index = 0;

fid = fopen("P.txt", "r");
if (fid == NULL){printf("Error opening the Probabilities file\n");}

while (!feof(fid))
{
  // P's values are double!
  if (fscanf(fid," double sum = 0;%lf\n", &temp_P))
  {
     Nodes[index].p_t1 = temp_P;
     index++;   
  }
}
//printf("End of P insertion!");

fclose(fid);    

}


/***** Read E vector from txt file*****/    

void Read_E_from_txt_file()
{

FILE *fid;
double temp_E;
int index = 0;

fid = fopen("E.txt", "r");
if (fid == NULL)
  printf("Error opening the E file\n");

while (!feof(fid))
{
  // E's values are double!
  if (fscanf(fid,"%lf\n", &temp_E))
  {
     Nodes[index].e = temp_E;
     index++;   
  }
}
//printf("End of E insertion!");

fclose(fid);    

}

/***** Create P and E with equal probability *****/

void Random_P_E()
{

int i;
// Sum of P (it must be =1)
double sum_P_1 = 0;
 // Sum of E (it must be =1)
double sum_E_1 = 0; 

// Arrays initialization
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  Nodes[i].p_t0 = 0;
  Nodes[i].p_t1 = 1;
  Nodes[i].p_t1 = (double) Nodes[i].p_t1 / N;

  sum_P_1 = sum_P_1 + Nodes[i].p_t1;

  Nodes[i].e = 1;
  Nodes[i].e = (double) Nodes[i].e / N;
  sum_E_1 = sum_E_1 + Nodes[i].e;
}

// Assert sum of probabilities is =1

// Print sum of P (it must be =1)
//printf("Sum of P = %f\n",sum_P_1);

// Exit if sum of P is !=1
assert(sum_P_1 = 1);

//printf("\n");

// Print sum of E (it must be =1)
//printf("Sum of E = %f\n",sum_E_1);

// Exit if sum of Pt0 is !=1
assert(sum_E_1 = 1);

}


/***** Main function *****/   

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int blockSize;      // The launch configurator returned block size 
int minGridSize;    // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the maximum occupancy for a full device launch 
int gridSize;       // The actual grid size needed, based on input size 

// Check input arguments
if (argc < 5)
{
  printf("Error in arguments! Three arguments required: graph filename, N, threshold and d\n");
  return 0;
} 

// get arguments 
char filename[256];
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
N = atoi(argv[2]);
threshold = atof(argv[3]);
d = atof(argv[4]);

int i;


// a constant value contributed of all nodes with connectivity = 0
// it's going to be addes to all node's new probability


// Allocate memory for N nodes
Nodes = (Node*) malloc(N * sizeof(Node));

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   Nodes[i].con_size = 0;
   //Nodes[i].To_id = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
}

Read_from_txt_file(filename);

// set random probabilities
Random_P_E();


Node *h_ingoing;

Node *h_outgoing;

h_ingoing = Nodes;

h_outgoing = (Node *)calloc(N, sizeof *h_outgoing);

Node *d_ingoing;

Node *d_outgoing;

cudaMalloc(&d_ingoing, N * sizeof *d_ingoing);

cudaMalloc(&d_outgoing, N * sizeof *d_outgoing);

cudaMemcpy(d_ingoing, h_ingoing, N * sizeof *h_ingoing, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpy(d_outgoing, h_outgoing, N * sizeof *h_outgoing, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

float time;

cudaEvent_t begin, end;

cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize, &blockSize, pagerank, 0, N); 

// Round up according to array size 
gridSize = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize; 
printf("Gridsize, blockzise : %d , %d \n", gridSize, blockSize);

cudaEventCreate(&begin);

cudaEventCreate(&end);
cudaEventRecord(begin, 0);

pagerank<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_ingoing, d_outgoing, N, threshold, d);

cudaEventRecord(end, 0);


cudaEventSynchronize(end);


cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, begin, end);

cudaMemcpy(h_outgoing, d_outgoing, N * sizeof *h_outgoing, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf("%f\n", time) ;



printf("\n");

// Print final probabilitities
for (i = 0; i <100; i++)
{
  printf("P_t1[%d] = %f\n",i,h_outgoing[i].p_t1);
}
printf("\n");



printf("End of program!\n");

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you get? I'm not a living compiler...

Comment: I believe I understand the question, though without the code calling the global kernel, it is hard to know what is going on.

Comment: I wrote the whole code, can you please explain now? thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you say *main function they print 0s when I do*, I assume you are refering to all entries and not just index 0. Indeed, index 0 is not processed by your code with the fisrt version as `((idx > 0) && (idx < N))` is false for `idx=0`.

Getting further, in your code, we are missing the definition of the `Node` type. which is mandatory to get a better understanding of what could go wrong in your code.

Depending on the size of `Node`, its contents, and the structure packing you are using in compilation, it might be that `Node` size on host side differs from `Node` size on device. Using `printf` to verify that would be usefull, or using a debugger.

Also, you do not seem to be checking for error in launch. You definitely want to add a [cudaPeekAtLastError](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__ERROR.html#group__CUDART__ERROR_1ge9f0596369c32aa43875c17c78a8fe41) and a [cudaDeviceSynchronize](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g10e20b05a95f638a4071a655503df25d) after your kernel call to make sure no error occurred. (any other method call from cuda Runtime API may also return errors your code does not check).

**EDIT**
Trying to reproduce, I wrote the following, as close as possible to your code. I don't have a card with sufficient memory, hence the smaller node count.

```
typedef struct 
{
    double p_t0;
    double p_t1;
    double e;
    int To_id[460];
    int con_size;
} Node ;

__global__ void pagerank(Node* ingoing, Node* outgoing, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x ; 
    if ((idx > 0) && (idx < N))
        outgoing[idx].p_t1 = ingoing[idx].p_t1;
}

#include <cstdlib>

#define cudaCheck(a) { cudaError_t cuerr = a ; if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) { printf("[ERROR @ %s : %d ] : (%d) - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cuerr, cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)) ; ::exit(1) ; } } 

int main()
{
    // int N = 916428 ; // does not fit on my GPU
    int N = 400000 ;

    int blockSize;
    int minGridSize;
    int gridSize;

    Node* Nodes = (Node*)malloc(N * sizeof (Node)) ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
        Nodes[i].p_t1 = (double)i+1;

    Node* h_ingoing = Nodes;
    Node* h_outgoing = (Node*)calloc(N, sizeof *h_outgoing) ;

    Node* d_ingoing ;
    Node* d_outgoing ;

    cudaCheck (cudaMalloc(&d_ingoing, N * sizeof *d_ingoing));
    cudaCheck (cudaMalloc(&d_outgoing, N * sizeof *d_outgoing));

    cudaCheck (cudaMemcpy (d_ingoing, h_ingoing, N * sizeof *h_ingoing, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudaCheck (cudaMemcpy (d_outgoing, h_outgoing, N * sizeof *h_outgoing, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    float time;

    cudaEvent_t begin, end ;

    //blockSize = 256 ;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize<> (&minGridSize, &blockSize, pagerank, 0, N) ;
    gridSize = (N + blockSize -1) / blockSize ;

    printf ("Configuration = <<< %d , %d >>>\n", gridSize, blockSize) ;

    cudaCheck (cudaEventCreate (&begin)) ;
    cudaCheck (cudaEventCreate (&end)) ;

    cudaCheck (cudaEventRecord (begin, 0)) ;

    pagerank <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_ingoing, d_outgoing, N) ;

    cudaCheck (cudaEventRecord (end, 0)) ;

    cudaCheck (cudaEventSynchronize (end)) ;

    cudaCheck (cudaMemcpy (h_outgoing, d_outgoing, N * sizeof *h_outgoing, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)) ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        printf ("P_t1[%d] = %f\n", i, h_outgoing[i].p_t1) ;
    }

    for (int i = 0  ; i < N ; ++i)
    {
        if (h_outgoing[i].p_t1 != (double)(i+1))
            printf ("Error @ %d : %lf <> %lf\n", i, h_outgoing[i].p_t1, (double)(i+1));
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Except at index 0 for which the first draft of answer stated there was an issue, each output is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I added the node description below. Does this change anything?

Comment: Node is a large structure. You are not getting any runtime error ?

Comment: Actually the total size of the Node matrix (there are 916428 Nodes) is 1.7 Gbit. I am running on a tesla k20m. No I am not receiving any error, at least not without a debugging tool

Comment: I updated the answer post with an attempt to reproduce. Re your last comment, what do you mean by "at least not without a debugging tool" ?

Comment: I am not receiving any error without a debugging tool. Like cuda memcheck. I ll try later with debugging tool and let you know